# How to create subtasks using JIRA REST Java Client

Tags: java, api, jira

Is there a way to create a subtask using JRJC v1.0? I've been unable to find any good documentation on this. Any sample codes out there?

It seems like it's not supported via the library but possible using straight REST API.

JIRA v5.1.5

Comment: what is the Jira version?

Comment: Updated my post with the JIRA version. I ended up using the REST API and got it working. It would still be good to know if this can be done with the JRJC lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create an issue as you normally would ([example](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/65115/create-an-issue-in-jira-rest-java-client#answer-container-112992)), but set the issue type to the required subtask type. Then, to link the subtask to it's parent use [`linkIssue`](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client/1.0/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/IssueRestClient.html#linkIssue%28com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.domain.input.LinkIssuesInput,%20com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.ProgressMonitor%29), something like:

```
LinkIssuesInput linkIssuesInput = new LinkIssuesInput("TST-1", "TST-2", "jira_subtask_link", Comment.valueOf("simple comment"));
issueClient.linkIssue( linkIssuesInput , pm);
```

I haven't tested it myself, I've used the [XML-RPC](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+XML-RPC+Overview) in old JIra, and [python-jira](http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in new ones. The full API is available [here](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client/1.0/apidocs/)

Comment: getting following error after following steps mentioned by you
`Caused by: com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.RestClientException: Issue type is a sub-task but parent issue key or id not specified.` . How can I get the fromIssueKey without creating the newIssue? since after setting issueType as sub-task it asks for parent key but this field is not there in Issue interface.

Comment: For an existing subtask, I was able to get the magic `jira_subtask_link` issue link to make the existing subtask appear under a different parent. However, it didn't remove the subtask from the current parent. I don't see how to get the id for these magic issue links. Any ideas?

Comment: They don't have any checks, you can create circular parent-child relations...
    LinkIssuesInput linkIssuesInput = new LinkIssuesInput( "1", "2", "jira_subtask_link");  

    LinkIssuesInput linkIssuesInput = new LinkIssuesInput( "2", "1", "jira_subtask_link");

Answer (score 5):

I was able to put together the below code that worked.

```
    IssueInputBuilder issueBuilder = new IssueInputBuilder("Project1", 5L);//5 is the id for subtask type. You can know the id of subtask type by querying this REST api /rest/api/2/issue/createmeta
    issueBuilder.setDescription(">> Test Description");
    issueBuilder.setSummary("Test summary");
    issueBuilder.setProjectKey("Project1");
    Map<String, Object> parent = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parent.put("key", "SOMEISSUE-234");
    FieldInput parentField = new FieldInput("parent", new ComplexIssueInputFieldValue(parent));

    Map<String, Object> customField = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    customField.put("value", "someValue");//This is some custom field value on the subtask
    customField.put("id", "12345");//This is the id of the custom field. You can know this by calling REST GET for a manually created sub-task

    issueBuilder.setFieldInput(parentField);
    issueBuilder.setFieldValue("customfield_12345",  new ComplexIssueInputFieldValue(customField));//here again you have to query an existing subtask to know the "customfield_*" value

    com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.domain.input.IssueInput issueInput = issueBuilder.build();
    BasicIssue bIssue = restClient.getIssueClient().createIssue(issueInput, pm);    
    System.out.println(">>> " + bIssue.getKey());
```

Comment: this worked for me and did not require any further linking using LinkIssuesInput etc. to get it to associate with the parent story.  the setFieldInput to parent seemed to do it.  thanks @jayP

Answer (score 2):

The REST API http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#id326540 has a comment:

Creating a sub-task is similar to creating a regular issue, with two important differences:

the issueType field must correspond to a sub-task issue type (you can use /issue/createmeta to discover sub-task issue types), and
you must provide a parent field in the issue create request containing the id or key of the parent issue.

So I think that the regular createIssue method should work, but you need to make sure you have passed in an extra FieldInput object constructed with ("parent", "ABC-123")

I'd be surprised if linking using the subtask link type actually works.